# Lattice grouped dot plot with conditional fill color

Tags: r, plot, lattice

### Problem:

I have two data frames, which I want to visualize with lattice's panel dot plot (not ggplot2) using the `make.groups()` function to group both data frames. Both data frames contain a variable which should be used conditionally to highlight data by different color fill. So in this case the `groups` argument handles the distinction between both data frames by the variable `which` generated by `make.groups()`.

### Reproducible example:

```
require(lattice)

# Make reproducable data frame
df= mtcars
df= cbind(car = rownames(df), df) 
rownames(df)= NULL
df= df[1:5, c("car", "mpg", "cyl", "carb")]

# Split into 2 dataframes
df.1= df
df.2= df
# Generate slightly different values in 2nd data frame
df.2$mpg= df.2$mpg + rnorm(1,2)

# I am interested to highlight those data which have carb=1
df.1[df.1$carb==1,]
df.2[df.2$carb==1,]

#             car  mpg cyl carb
#3     Datsun 710 22.8   4    1
#4 Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6    1
#
#             car      mpg cyl carb
#3     Datsun 710 25.53714   4    1
#4 Hornet 4 Drive 24.13714   6    1

myTheme= standard.theme(col = FALSE)
myTheme$superpose.symbol$pch= 1:7
par.settings = myTheme

dotplot(car ~ mpg | as.factor(cyl), 
        data=make.groups(df.1, df.2), 
        layout=c(3,1),
        par.settings = myTheme,
        groups = which, 
        auto.key=TRUE)
```

This creates a plot:

[image]

### Question:

I'd like to achieve following plot:

[image]

How can I refactor the code to achieve this?

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Lattice dotplot conditional fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544194/lattice-dotplot-conditional-fill-color) as the question here is close but different and more complicated. The same answer may not be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I found the `as.layer()` function in the [latticeExtra](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#as.layer&theme=default) package as a solution.

I am not sure whether this is the most elegant way, but selective highlighting (in this case only colored symbol instead of requested fill) works:

```
require(latticeExtra)

 dotplot(car ~ mpg | as.factor(cyl), 
        data=make.groups(df.1, df.2), 
        layout=c(3,1),
        par.settings = myTheme,
        cex=1,
        groups = which, 
        auto.key=TRUE) +
  as.layer(dotplot(car ~ mpg | as.factor(cyl),
                   data=make.groups(df.1, df.2),
                   groups=carb<2,
                   cex=0.5,
                   pch=19,
                   col= c("white", "red"))
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Borrowed from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544194/lattice-dotplot-conditional-fill-color?lq=1 plus latticeExtra. Not really nice as the symbol is not completely filled. Hoping for a better solution.